# Android create alert dialog options dynamically from string array

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-dialog

I want to create an Dialog options menu on click of a listview item. Its working perfectly when using static string array for dialog options. But using dynamic values its showing only an item with comma separated.

Here is my code

```
  StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
        String delimiter = "";
        for(int i = 0; i< myarray.length;i++){
            builder.append(delimiter);
            builder.append(myarray[i]);
            delimiter = ",";  
        }


    String[] Options = new String[] { "Reply" ,builder.toString()};

    AlertDialog.Builder dialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
    dialog.setTitle("TEst");
    dialog.setItems(Options, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {

            if (id == 0) {

            }
            if (id == 1) {

            }

        }
    });
dialog.show();
```

Comment: do you create dialog in overridden onCreateDialog() method of your activity?

Comment: @Candy myarray is a string array pouplated from json

Comment: @Candy Yes they are string values

Comment: issue solved using array merging